# Laravel run process continuously on Forge server

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

In a previous app built in CodeIgniter I've put a script on the server which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
        php /var/www/html/index.php nameOfController nameOfScript
        sleep 1
done
```

And then I would run it using `nohup scriptname`.

I was wondering how you do this for a Laravel app. It will be hosted on DigitalOcean and deployed via Forge but I don't think that will make any difference.

Would the script be the same for Laravel? As I'm not yet in production I was wondering if anyone has experience in setting up such a script.

**Update**

The reason why I'd like to run it this way is because it's a script that trades on crypto exchanges. Sometimes (because of low quality APIs...) the script will take 1 second, but sometimes it takes 15 seconds. If I use a cronjob say every 1 second, and the script is still running after 1 second, the cron job will let it run again without it being finished (which is crucial for the app). Therefore I'd like a script that keeps running the same function over and over again, but not at a set time interval.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/scheduling

Comment: I don’t want to use cron. The shortest repeat time is a minute which way too slow. Even it it would be shorter, it will always run the script with a set interval. I don’t want that, but instead have the script run continuously. Because sometimes the script will take 1 second, sometimes up to 30 seconds. Regardless, it needs to repeat directly after its done.

Comment: @RossWilson I've added some details

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Swoole](https://www.swoole.co.uk) integrated with Laravel in the forge, you can make a [Millisecond cron job](https://github.com/hhxsv5/laravel-s#millisecond-cron-job).

If you are not using Swoole, you can put a program in your forge `supervisord.conf` file like this:

```
[program:schedule]
command = bash %(ENV_APP_DIR)s/schedule.sh
stdout_logfile = /dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile = /dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
user = root
autostart = true
autorestart = true
priority = 500
```

And in the schedule.sh

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    php artisan yourcommand
    sleep 5
done
```

But definitely Swoole millisecond cron jobs are a better way to manage this, cause you have more control of time and execution.